# shell script adds space when calling variables

Tags: python, bash, shell

I stumble over a strange behavior of a `#!/bin/bash` script.

I got the variable `SD=/SOME_VALID_PATH` and `SCRIPT=SOME_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py`. What I want to do now in my script is `eval python ${SD}/${SCRIPT}`.

What happens is that the result looks like `python /SOME_VALID_PATH/ SOME_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py`. Note the space between the path and the script's name, so naturally, this command is not executed.

`echo ${SD}` gives `/SOME_VALID_PATH` and `echo ${SCRIPT}` gives `SOME_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py`, no spaces whatsoever.

Any ideas what I (generally) might do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you want to use `eval`?

Comment: BTW, in general, you cannot trust `echo` to give anything resembling an honest and accurate representation of how something will expand. Keep in mind that `mkdir "directory with spaces"` and `mkdir directory with spaces` do completely different things, but `echo "directory with spaces"` and `echo directory with spaces` are indistinguishable.

Comment: Use `bash -x yourscript` to run your script with logging of each command the shell runs. And [don't use `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) unless you have enough years of expertise to understand (1) *why* you're being advised not to use `eval`, and (2) *how* not to use `eval`.

Comment: Beyond that -- we need a [mcve] before we can provide a canonical and complete answer to your question. Right now, you haven't provided anything we can copy-and-paste to see the error you're experiencing ourselves, so we don't know the details of the problem. Maybe your `IFS` contains a character present in the `SD` variable, maybe `SD` has a hidden/non-printable character and/or a control character that moves the cursor around, maybe there's something else going on -- without a reproducer, all we can do is guess.

Comment: ...oh -- and don't use all-caps names for your own variables. All-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system and shell; the namespace of variables with at least one lower-case character is [guaranteed safe for applications to use without conflicting with POSIX-specified utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (see fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a namespace).

Comment: (btw, instead of `echo ${SD}`, use `printf '%q=%q\n' SD "$SD" SCRIPT "$SCRIPT"` to emit the values of your variables in unambiguous form).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you're trying to use eval the way you mentioned (as mentioned in the comments a sample of your code will be helpful). It is likely the error you mentioned is because `eval` concatenates the string provided as its argument and it is your responsibility to make sure that the command syntax is correct. So it may be that python is getting the path (SD) and SCRIPT as two different arguments (separated by space) and so it fails to execute the path which is probably a directory.

You can use *command substitution* with `eval` and `echo` for example to make sure that the strings are properly represented. An example is given below where I have defined two variables for path and script name. The script name contains a space so a normal eval will throw an error.

```
$ echo $var1
/home/user/Documents/Temp
$ echo $var2
temp.py
$ echo  \"$var1/$var2\"
"/home/user/Documents/Temp/ temp.py"
$ cat "$(echo $var1/$var2)"
print "Hello World"
$ eval python $var1/$var2
/home/user/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/user/Documents/Temp/'
$ eval python $(echo  \"$var1/$var2\")
Hello World
```

But this is probably not the best way to do things. Spaces should be avoided in paths.

Comment: I disagree that "spaces should be avoided in paths". If good practices are followed to keep data and code separate from each other, spaces are completely harmless. If good practices *aren't* followed (as in both the OP's request and the example here), you have much more severe problems (ie. vulnerabilities to shell injection attacks).

Comment: I completely agree that from programmer's point of view, good practices must be adopted so that the code will work for all types of allowed filenames. However from the file creator's point of view, when there is an option to choose between whitespace and another non-whitespace character I will always prefer something like underscore especially in a Unix like system. It is just as readable, plays well with tab completion, results in simpler regexes/glob patterns and makes it much more convenient to use the name with bash utilities like cat, ls, grep etc in the command line.